# compare a char in char* with a loop

Tags: c, char

How can I compare a character with `char*` character in c ?
Below is my case.

```
char *str = "this is testing"
for (i=0; i<strlen(str); i++)
{
    if (strcmp(str[i], 't') == 0)
        printf("%c\n", str[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To just compare one character, you don't need `strcmp` -- you can do it yourself.

```
if (str[i] == 't') {
```

For that matter, you don't need `strlen` either -- since C strings are null-terminated, you can just iterate until you see the NUL value, thus doing one pass through the string rather than two (the first being within `strlen` itself):

```
for(i=0; str[i] != 0; i++) {
  if(str[i] == 't') {
    printf("%c\n", str[i]);
  }
}
```